# IOS/Objective-C: Lazy load UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a label programatically.  Unfortunately, I've discovered that every time I update the label, I am creating a new instance.  Is there a way to check if a UILabel already exists before you create it?

This is my current code to create label:

```
UILabel *percentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, height, 280, 20)];
```

If I condition it on following, I get error that it does not recognize label:

```
for (id percentLabel in self.view.subviews) {
        if (![percentLabel isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
          UILabel *percentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, height, 280, 20)];
        }
    percentLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: right now it is in its own method where I do various stuff to calculate percent.  The method is called when you change things that would change percent.

Comment: Take the initial case when self.view has no subviews, it won't enter the loop and no UILabel is created and if the self.view has some subviews which are not UILabels then new UILabels will be created and won't be used at all because when it exists the if condition the label instance is released and also the app will crash as it is trying to find textAlignment on some other type of view which has no property textAlignment (ie, what's happening with your code now). If the self.view has UILabel view's it will align the text.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish in your original code? There is not enough code showing to know if other important things are being done ... like addSubView - are you calling that?

Comment: do you added `percentLabel` as a subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to check the object existence. In your example the if statement will create a label on every single iteration of the `for` cycle. A fixed version of that code will look like this:

```
UILabel *percentLabel = nil;
for (id subview in self.view.subviews) {
  if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
    percentLabel = (UILabel *)subview;
    break;
  }
}
if (!percentLabel) {
  // Label creation code here
}
```

However I would suggest you to store that label as a property in your view controller and initialize it lazily as it shown below:

```
...
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *percentLabel;
...

- (UILabel *)percentLabel {
  if (!_percentLabel) {
    UILabel *percentLabel = /* initialization code here */;
    // Add percent label as a subview to your view
    _percentLabel = percentLabel;
  }

  return _percentLabel;
}
```

Note that I'm storing the property with a weak reference, because your view will actually own that label and keep a strong reference via it's `subviews` property.

Comment: I got it to work through this approach of alloc initing the label once in view did load and then storing it in a property as shown here.  Then I update percent label.text property as data changes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are looping over your subviews (some of which might not actually be labels) and you are trying to change the text alignment.

There are better ways to keep track of a label instance then looping over the subviews every time, such as setting a class property like:

```
UILabel *labelToChange;
```

in your interface decleration in your .h file.

Then in your implementation simply access the label using

```
labelToChange.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Just make sure you only `[UILabel alloc] init` once to initialise an instance of `UILabel`

Comment: Right now I am initing the label with a variable for its y origin (height).  Maybe I should just alloc init the label with an arbitrary value for its origin and then change it later.  But I was hoping there was a way to lazy alloc init

Comment: Unfortunately just changing the value of a variable that you have used in a frame wont change the frame of the label. You have to explicitly pass the label a completely new frame if you want to move it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to set a unique tag to your UILabel that way you do not need to check the class. Remember that there are even UILabel in UITableView, UINavigationBar, and so, and you don't want to mess with those.

So, what you should do is create 2 separate methods: one to create label and be called in viewDidLoad ONCE, and another is to update the label.

Create method:

```
-(void)createLabels {
  UILabel *percentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, height, 280, 20)];
  percentLabel.tag = 1111; // a unique tag
  [self.view addSubview:percentLabel];
}
```

Update method:

```
-(void)updateLabelWithText:(NSString*)newText {
  UILabel *yourLabel = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:1111];
  yourLabel.text = newText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  give `percentLabel` a unique `tag` value.

then you can use `viewWithTag` to get `percentLabel`, like

```
    UILabel *percentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, height, 280, 20)];
percentLabel.tag = 100;
[self.view addSubview:percentLabel];

//In another method
UILabel *percenLabel = [self.view viewWithTag:100];
if (percentLabel == nil) {
    percentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, height, 280, 20)];
    percentLabel.tag = 100;
    percentLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:percentLabel];
}
else {
    percentLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```